# Is this SuperFashHash implementation computing a proper 31-bit hash of a string?

Tags: algorithm, vba, hash, excel

I'm implementing a variation of the SuperFastHash in VBA for use in Excel (32-bit version, so no LongLong available) to hash strings.

To get around the limitations of signed 32-bit Long values, I'm doing the addition and bit-shifting using Double types, and then converting from Double to Long in a way that truncates it at 31 bits (the maximum positive value -- don't want to deal with two's complement and signs).

I'm getting answers and avoiding overflows so far, but I have a suspicion I'm making some mistakes in translation, since most implementations use all 32 bits of a uint and also deal with individual bytes from an array rather than 16-bit values coming from AscW().

Specific portions of the implementation I'm hoping someone can gut-check:

1. How I'm testing 16-bit character words rather than 4-byte chunks.
2. Whether my bit-shifting operations are technically correct, given the caveat that I need to truncate Long values at 31 bits.
3. Whether the final avalanche piece is still appropriate given the hash only uses 31 bits.

Here's the current code:

```
Public Function shr(ByVal Value As Long, ByVal Shift As Byte) As Long
    shr = Value
    If Shift > 0 Then shr = shr \ (2 ^ Shift)
End Function

Public Function shl(ByVal Value As Long, ByVal Shift As Byte) As Long
    If Shift > 0 Then
        shl = LimitDouble(CDbl(Value) * (2& ^ Shift))
    Else
        shl = Value
    End If
End Function

Public Function LimitDouble(ByVal d As Double) As Long
    '' Prevent overflow by lopping off anything beyond 31 bits
    Const MaxNumber As Double = 2 ^ 31
    LimitDouble = CLng(d - (Fix(d / MaxNumber) * MaxNumber))
End Function

Public Function SuperFastHash(ByVal dataToHash As String) As Long
    Dim dataLength As Long
    dataLength = Len(dataToHash)
    If (dataLength = 0) Then
        SuperFastHash = 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim hash As Long
    hash = dataLength
    Dim remainingBytes As Integer
    remainingBytes = dataLength Mod 2
    Dim numberOfLoops As Integer
    numberOfLoops = dataLength \ 2
    Dim currentIndex As Integer
    currentIndex = 0
    Dim tmp As Double
    Do While (numberOfLoops > 0)
        hash = LimitDouble(CDbl(hash) + AscW(Mid$(dataToHash, currentIndex + 1, 1)))
        tmp = shl(AscW(Mid$(dataToHash, currentIndex + 2, 1)), 11) Xor hash
        hash = shl(hash, 16) Xor tmp
        hash = LimitDouble(CDbl(hash) + shr(hash, 11))
        currentIndex = currentIndex + 2
        numberOfLoops = numberOfLoops - 1
    Loop
    If remainingBytes = 1 Then
        hash = LimitDouble(CDbl(hash) + AscW(Mid$(dataToHash, currentIndex + 1, 1)))
        hash = hash Xor shl(hash, 10)
        hash = LimitDouble(CDbl(hash) + shr(hash, 1))
    End If
    '' Final avalanche
    hash = hash Xor shl(hash, 3)
    hash = LimitDouble(CDbl(hash) + shr(hash, 5))
    hash = hash Xor shl(hash, 4)
    hash = LimitDouble(CDbl(hash) + shr(hash, 17))
    hash = hash Xor shl(hash, 25)
    hash = LimitDouble(CDbl(hash) + shr(hash, 6))
    SuperFastHash = hash
End Function
```

Comment: No offense, but what's the point of micro optimizing vba code ? Wouldn't a simple hash do ?

Comment: @AlexandreC., this *is* a simple hash algorithm. VBA does not include an intrinsic hash function and I'd rather not re-invent the wheel, so Paul Hsieh's algorithm seemed to be a good fit. Existing VBA implementations of MD5 that I've found are 10x slower.

Comment: You might want to post this over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Added there, but traffic on that site is nowhere near that of SO. I'm not so much looking for random code improvements overall as I am some idea of whether I've implemented the algorithm successfully *and* modified it to return a 31-bit answer in a reasonable way.

Comment: SuperFashHash. I like the sound of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that rather than messing around with doubles, you would probably be better off splitting the 32-bit word into two "16-bit" parts, each of which is held in a signed 32-bit variable (use the lower 16 bits of each variable, and then "normalize" the value between steps:

```
highPart = (highPart + (lowPart \ 65536)) and 65535
lowPart = lowPart and 65535
```

Shifting left 16 places simply means copying the low part to the high part and zeroing the low part.  Shifting right 16 places simply means copying the high part to the low part and zeroing the high part.  Shifting left a smaller number of places simply means shifting both parts separately and then normalizing.  Shifting a normalized number right a smaller number of places means shifting both parts left (16-N) bits, normalizing, and shifting right 16 bits.

Comment: A very good point -- I was thinking something similar earlier, along with creating a "UInt" class to encapsulate the grimy details. An Integer plus a Boolean would also work (though I agree two ints is better).

I still feel like I may be misinterpreting the original algorithm and that I should be processing the MSB/LSB of each Unicode character separately. I would expect such things to possibly drastically impact the hash distribution.

Comment: @richardtallent: I am not familiar enough with the original algorithm to comment about that, but would suggest that folding a 32-bit algorithm to a 31-bit algorithm by dropping the MSB is often not a good approach.  Better in many cases would be to have it influence other bits in some fashion, perhaps by xor'ing any negative number with an arbitrary negative constant which is orthogonal to anything inherent in the algorithm.  As the design of a "uint", I think a pair of integers is the way to go, since most operations can be done on the halves individually wothout overflow.

Comment: @richardtallent: The only operations which cannot be performed by doing them 'rough' and then normalizing are are multiplication (since 65535*65535 exceeds the range of a vba `Integer`) and long division (which is tends to be somewhat painful no matter how you slice it).  Long division might be done best by converting to `Double`, doing the math, and converting back.  Multiplication of full-range 16-bit values X and Y when both X and Y are at least 32768 can be done by recognizing that X*Y = 65536*Y+(X-65536)*Y.

Comment: I ended up implementing this, and can now produce a 32-bit hash. Not sure if the hash itself is a correct implementation of the algorithm, but at least I'm not dealing with Overflows at this point.